# Paste location in Ubuntu download dialog box

Tags: 20.04, gnome, nautilus

I generally download things to different folders deep inside the `$USER/Desktop`. I wish I could simply press CRTL + L in Nautilus to get the full path and paste it into the Download dialog box. But it seems I have to click to navigate all the way to my preferred download location. There is no way to just paste the location using Keyboard in the Download dialog box.

I am using Ubuntu LTS 20.04.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your cursor in the "Name" field (which it will be right after opening the dialog), hit <kbd>Home</kbd> then (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) to paste your pathname before the file name. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file in the target location.

If you enter the path without the file name, hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> will cause the dialog to stay open in the target path, ready for you to add the name.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> works in a File Open dialog to display the pathbar. In a File Save dialog, the name field already is the path bar.

Comment: thanks it works.